# Collision of grenadelauncher shell

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics

The shell of a grenadelauncher is very small (10cm) and the speed is very fast (80m/s). Collision detection using colliders is impossible.

To get the collision point of a rocket launcher I send a Ray out from the rocket with a length of say 5 metres. If the Ray detects an object it will wait for 5/SpeedOfRocket seconds and then detonate. A rocket travels in a straight line, therefore no problem:
[image]

Grenades however travel in an Arch. They are not selfpropelled, they slow down due to air resistance and they are pulled down by gravity. If I fire a grenade up into the air and use a Ray to detect the collision, it will simply fall through the floor, or another object. The grenade doesn't rotate towards the direction of travel.

[image]

Using a second and third Ray to detect collisions behind and below the grenade catch all collisions successfully. However you will not be able to shoot a grenade closely above a hill or through a narrow window without it triggering a collision if within range of the Ray.

[image]

**For now** I have "solved" the problem by using the grenade just like a rocket. I simulate gravity by simply rotating the grenade as it moves. One ray to catch collision is enough because the Grenade will always face the direction of travel.

[image]

It works fine if you use the Grenade Launcher "normally". Until you shoot it like a mortar launcher: straight up in the air. I find it mathematically impossible to simulate the trajectory as such. There are too many variables involved and it would be a ridiculous attempt at solving a (what seems to be) a trivial initial problem.

I need to get the grenade to face the direction of travel like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're describing is called *tunneling*.  It happens with small fast objects in discrete simulations, because the simulation timestep makes them simply skip past other objects without a collision being noticed.

The simplest fix is to use a *swept collider*.

1. For every fast object, store the previous frame's position.  Here's how that state would look on the frame that the fast object (red) enters another collider (green):

   [image: previous and current position]
2. Every frame, construct a collider that "fills in" the space the grenade would have traveled through between its previous and current positions:

   [image: swept collider]

   Be as fancy with this as you think is necessary for the accuracy that you want.  A raycast might be close enough for small objects.
3. When that swept collider hits, raycast from the previous position to find the impact point.

   [image: raycast]

   Of course, you don't need to do this separately if you already did a raycast for the previous step.  Again you can be as sophisticated as necessary here, potentially using a "thick ray" if the exact bounding volume is important.

Comment: You're an actual legend